# Como fazer o mavem obter o jar sempre da branch master

Tags: git, maven

Tenho 2 projetos gerenciados pelo maven. 
O primeiro é o Model.
O Segundo o Front End e o Controll
O model é uma dependência do FrontEnd.
Faço isso com a seguinte dependencia no pom.xml do projeto FrontEnd.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId> 
   <artifactId>alvoradaModel</artifactId> 
   <version>1.2.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Tenho o controle dos dois projetos pelo Git.
e para isso utilizo duas Branchs: a master e a desenvolvimento

Como faço para que o alvoradaModel seja obtido sempre da branch master mesmo que a ativa no momento seja a desenvolvimento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um [plugin](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22pl.project13.maven%22) do Maven para resolver seu problema, o [maven git commit id plugin](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin) esta no githup explicando [como utilizar](https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin#using-the-plugin), basicamente é so alterar o `.pom.xml`:

Você pode usá-lo para obter o `branch` git com

```
${git.branch}
```

Então, no seu caso, seria:

```
<version>${git.branch}</version>
```

<sup>Fonte: [put-current-git-branch-to-project-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553304/put-current-git-branch-to-project-version)</sup>